# How to use a Cell Reference to a Comparison Operator within Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, comparison-operators

In Google Sheets, can you do a cell reference, to a cell with a comparison operator ( >, <, >=, <=, <> ) in it, within conditional formatting?

For instance, you want to test =A1>A3, but rather than typing the > directly into the conditional formatting formula, you have a > in cell A2.  This way the user can see what comparison operator is being used for conditional formatting, and change it if needed.

So the conditional formatting formula would be something like =A1 & A2 & A3 or maybe =A1&"A2"&A3.  But these do not work.

Here is my attempt:

[conditional formatting formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlS8.png)

Do you know how to accomplish this?  Thank you!

Comment: You have to use `INDIRECT()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Formula building**

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,A2&A3),TRUE)
```

[image]

**Note**

> COUNTIF return 1 or 0
>
> Use IF to return TRUE or FALSE

---

**Conditional formatting** (just use **COUNTIF**)

```
=COUNTIF($S$20,$X$24&$Y$24)
```

[image]

**Function References**

- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)

Comment: What a thoroughly complete answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @DW glad to have helped you, please accept my answer